# how to remove words of specific length in a string in R?

Tags: regex, r, string, trim, gsub

I want to remove words of length less than 3 in a string. for example my input is

```
str<- c("hello RP have a nice day")
```

I want my output to be

```
str<- c("hello have nice day")
```

Please help

Comment: Better not use str as a variable name. str is a built-in function of R.

Comment: `gsub(' . | .. ', ' ', s)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
gsub('\\b\\w{1,2}\\b','',str)
[1] "hello  have  nice day"
```

**EDIT**
\b is word boundary. If need to drop extra space,change it as:

```
gsub('\\b\\w{1,2}\\s','',str)
```

Or

```
gsub('(?<=\\s)(\\w{1,2}\\s)','',str,perl=T)
```

Comment: perhaps add a bit of explanation as to what the regexes are doing?

Comment: I like the approach to use just base R. But all three solutions make one of these three "mistakes": (1) remove substrings of length 1 or 2 when connected to a longer substring through a minus (as in "co-selection"); (2) Not remove substrings of length 1 or 2 at the end of the string; (3) Not remove substrings at the beginning of the string. The first solution makes the first mistake, the second solution makes the second mistake, and the third solution makes the second and third mistake. How can I not make any of these mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

Or use `str_extract_all` to extract all words that have length >=3 and `paste`

```
library(stringr)
paste(str_extract_all(str, '\\w{3,}')[[1]], collapse=' ')
#[1] "hello have nice day"
```

Comment: there is an error what I got when I tried this.. `SubConsolData$ProductTitle <- paste(str_extract_all(SubConsolData$ProductTitle, '\\w{3,}')[[1]], collapse=' ')`  and the error is first row of DF (`SubConsolData`) is repeated to all the rest of the rows in the DF.

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque  It is because we are extracting the first element `[[1]]`.  In this case, there is only a single string.  In your case you may need to loop and then do the `paste`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using the `rm_nchar_words` function from the **qdapRegex** package that I coauthored with @hwnd (SO regex guru extraordinaire).  Here I show removing 1-2 letter words and then 1-3 letter words:

```
str<- c("hello RP have a nice day")

library(qdapTools)

rm_nchar_words(str, "1,2")
## [1] "hello have nice day"

rm_nchar_words(str, "1,3")
## [1] "hello have nice"
```

As **qdapRegex** aims to teach here is the regex behind the scene where the `S` function puts `1,2` into the quantifier curly braces:

```
S("@rm_nchar_words", "1,2")
##  "(?<![\\w'])(?:'?\\w'?){1,2}(?![\\w'])"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- "hello RP have a nice day"
z <- unlist(strsplit(x, split=" "))
paste(z[nchar(z)>=3], collapse=" ")
# [1] "hello have nice day"
```