# R Korean regexp

Tags: r, cjk, regexp-substr

I'm currently trying to remove a Korean letter where nchar is only equal to 1 in R.
For example,

```
have = "안녕 난 철수야"
want = "안녕 철수야"
```

I've found the Eng version of what it is that I'm trying to achieve.
[how to remove words of specific length in a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226616/how-to-remove-words-of-specific-length-in-a-string-in-r)
Can someone help me how I can do this but on Korean?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try

```
gsub('\\s\\p{Hangul}\\s',' ', have, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "안녕 철수야"
```